# ERROR: (gcloud.compute.tpus.tpu-vm.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on 'locations/us-central1-a\' (or it may not exist). and other Error

Tags: gcloud, tpu

I am attempting to follow the instructions to set up a gcloud tpu system from this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/setup-gcp-account#set-up-project). I have followed each of the instructions up to the Prepare to create a Cloud TPU section. It is at this point I am unsure what command to actually run given the parameters.

I have been trying different versions of the following command on both a cmd on my device and on the cloud shell terminal.

```
gcloud compute tpus tpu-vm create project6\ --zone=us-central1-a\ --accelerator-type=v2-32\ --version=tpu-vm-tf-2.15.0-pjrt\ --service-account=gavi-845@project6-409520.iam.gserviceaccount.com\ --reserved
```

On my device I get the error message

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.tpus.tpu-vm.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on 'locations/us-central1-a\' (or it may not exist).
```

While on the cloud shell I get

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.tpus.tpu-vm.create) argument --version: Must be specified.
```

I am assuming I did something wrong on my device given the error discrepancy, I m just not sure what.

I am not entirely sure what I am expecting as I am currently learning how all this works but I would at least like to be able to continue with the tutorial.

Comment: Remove the slashes on the command flags. Example: `--zone=us-central1-a\\`.